# How to start and stop processes in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, start-process

This should work fine in PowerShell older than 3. I need to run two processes: wuapp.exe and desk.cpl with ScreenSaver's tab. The problem I have is that once I start wuapp.exe the process name shows up in Task Manager as explorer.exe - the current code works for wuapp.exe but not on every machine. The other thing is when I kill rundll32 other apps will close also. What do you suggest?

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
Start-Process  wuapp.exe
(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}
Start-Process rundll32 desk.cpl,InstallScreenSaver
Stop-Process -ProcessName rundll32* -Force
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by `wuapp.exe` showing up as `explorer.exe`, but keeping track of the `rundll32` process is fairly straightforward.

Use `Start-Process` with the `PassThru` parameter to have it return the process it creates:

```
$ScreenSaverCpl = Start-Process rundll32 desk.cpl,InstallScreenSaver -PassThru
# Call Stop-Process when no longer needed:
Stop-Process $ScreenSaverCpl
```

Comment: The problem with wuapp.exe is that once I run it I see in Task Manager "Windows Update" but when I go to Processes it highlights explorer.exe and there is no such process as wuapp.exe. How can I track it?