# Change instance level collation of SQL Server using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, collation

I want to change the collation of SQL Server instance programmatically using powershell script. Followings are the manual steps:

1. Stop the SQL Server instance
2. Go to directory location: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\MSSQL\Binn"
3. Execute following command:  sqlservr -c -m -T4022 -T3659 -s"SQL2017" -q"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
4. After the execution of the above command, following message displayed: "The default collation was successfully changed."
5. Then I need to press ctrl+c to stop further execution. How can I do
   this programmatically?

Comment: `-q` is an undocumented, and more importantly unsupported, command line switch. There are all sorts of caveats that could lead to columns being in an undefined state and even data loss. REF: [Changing Collation - -q option?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea0f5487-72f8-478c-9635-cfcd70a54340/changin-collation-q-option?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: We will detach all user database first before doing these steps, and after completion, we will attach them.

Comment: How to execute following command using powershell:
 sqlservr -c -m -T4022 -T3659 -s"SQL2017" -q"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

Comment: See [How to start and stop processes in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898479/how-to-start-and-stop-processes-in-powershell). [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6) has switches that allow you to redirect STDOUT and STDERR outputs from the process to text files which you can monitor from PowerShell so as to [Stop-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-6) at the appropriate time.

Comment: Following code is working fine:
$process = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL S
erver\MSSQL14.SQL2017\MSSQL\Binn\SqlServr.exe" -ArgumentList "-c -m -T 4022 -T 3659 -s SQL2017 -q Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS" -NoNew
Window -PassThru -Wait
.
But, the process still continues. How to stop is programmatically after successfull collation change?
After collation change, following message gets displayed:
 The default collation was successfully changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we execute the command to change the SQL Server Collation, it logs the execution details in event viewer application logs. Using loop we can check the event viewer application logs for SqlServr.exe continuously, and when it generates the following log message: "The default collation was successfully changed", we can kill the process.

```
#Take the time stamp before execution of Collation Change Command
$StartDateTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)

# Execute the Collation Change Process
Write-Host "Executing SQL Server Collation Change Command"
$CollationChangeProcess=Start-Process -FilePath $SQLRootDirectory -ArgumentList 
"-c -m -T 4022 -T 3659 -s $JustServerInstanceName -q $NewCollationName" - 
NoNewWindow -passthru

Do
{
  $log=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='application'; 
  providername=$SQLServiceName; starttime = $StartDateTime} | Where-Object - 
  Property Message -Match 'The default collation was successfully changed.'
  IF($log.count -gt 0 -and  $log.TimeCreated -gt $StartDateTime )
  {
    Stop-Process -ID $CollationChangeProcess.ID
    write-host 'Collation Change Process Completed Successfully.'
    break
  }
  $DateTimeNow=(Get-Date)
  $Duration=$DateTimeNow-$StartDateTime
  write-host  $Duration.totalminutes
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
  IF ($Duration.totalminutes -gt 2)
  {
    write-host 'Collation Change Process Failed.'
    break
  }
 }while (1 -eq 1)
```

Comment: For more details, please see my blog: https://sqlscenarios.blogspot.com/2019/11/algorithm-to-automate-sql-server.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@Murali Dhar Darshan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58715234/1493471). I've made some changes to your solution to make it easier to use. (I don't have high enough reputation to add this as a comment to your answer).

```
# Params
$NewCollationName="Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS"
$SQLRootDirectory="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe"
$SQLServiceName="MSSQLSERVER"

# Stop running SQL instance
net stop $SQLServiceName 

#Take the time stamp before execution of Collation Change Command
$StartDateTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1)

# Execute the Collation Change Process
Write-Host "Executing SQL Server Collation Change Command"
$CollationChangeProcess=Start-Process -FilePath $SQLRootDirectory -ArgumentList "-c -m -T 4022 -T 3659 -q $NewCollationName" -NoNewWindow -passthru

Do
{
  $log=Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='application'; 
  providername=$SQLServiceName; starttime = $StartDateTime} | Where-Object -Property Message -Match 'The default collation was successfully changed.'
  IF($log.count -gt 0 -and  $log.TimeCreated -gt $StartDateTime )
  {
    Stop-Process -ID $CollationChangeProcess.ID
    write-host 'Collation Change Process Completed Successfully.'
    
    # Start SQL instance again
    net start $SQLServiceName 

    break
  }
  $DateTimeNow=(Get-Date)
  $Duration=$DateTimeNow-$StartDateTime
  write-host  $Duration.totalminutes
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
  IF ($Duration.totalminutes -gt 2)
  {
    write-host 'Collation Change Process Failed.'
    Stop-Process -ID $CollationChangeProcess.ID
    break
  }
 }while (1 -eq 1)
```