# Killing the process after certain output in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, collation

I am following undocumented approch to change the collation of sql server instance using below command:

```
sqlservr -m -T4022 -T3659 -s"SQL2017" -q"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI"
```

After execution of this command, after certain time we get following output:

```
"The default collation was successfully changed"
```

But even after this output, the process continues and we need to kill it by pressing CTRL+C button.
How I can achieve it using powershell? I want to automate this process.

Comment: I guess your following the instructions [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation/)... actually I'd prefer Option #3. If you want to automate your task.. then you might use the ```start-job``` cmdlet, followed by a ```start-sleep``` and ```stop-job``` command...

Comment: I posted the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337969/change-instance-level-collation-of-sql-server-using-powershell?noredirect=1#comment103033939_58337969

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable.

Something like this:

```
sqlservr -m -T4022 -T3659 -s"SQL2017" -q"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI"

if ($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0) {
    throw "Error changing server collation with the code '$LASTEXITCODE'"
}
```

Comment: I did not get your answer. Where we are assigning the variable $LASTEXITCODE?

Comment: $LastExitCode is a variable used by powershell for handling error. But now I realized that the sqlservr tool is returning a success message. My bad.

Comment: @MuraliDharDarshan That's a PowerShell automatic variable.  It is populated after running any external process.

Comment: It's a built-in variable, similar to %ErrorLevel% that cmd.exe provides. See [this PowerShell blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/errorlevel-equivalent/).

Comment: While executing above mentioned command, can we also look into event viewer? Because the command logs its events into there. If yes, then how to do it?